# How can I set the size of an object in cm, using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, monitor, dpi

I need to set the size of an object in cm/inches (or another value that is always the same on any monitor). I know the code to set the size in px, but not in a value that is always the same.

Comment: I highly doubt you can do this; to do it, you need to retrieve the current DPI value of the monitor and I don't know a way to get that value. Even more, it's very likely that that setting doesn't correspond with its *real* value.

Comment: “always the same on any monitor” — excuse me whilst I laugh bitterly for ten minutes.

Comment: @Paul D. Waite: Reminds me specs "layout must be exactly the same on every browser".

Comment: @Clement: indeed. Tells you a lot about the chump who wrote that sentence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In theory, you just use [the cm unit](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#length-units):

```
{
    width: 15cm;
    height: 10cm;
}
```

In practice, you can't do this automatically since this depends on:

- The computer being correctly calibrated for the monitor so it knows what the DPI of the display is for the resolution it is outputting
- The browser to calculate pixel sizes based on the system DPI and not its own assumptions

It is very rare for both of these to be true.

---

A workaround would be to display an image with a known pixel size and ask the user to measure it on their display. You could then calculate all your lengths based on that radio and set all widths, heights, etc with JavaScript. This would be more effort then most users would be willing to go to for most projects.

Answer (score -1):

Same answer as David Dorward.

Another solution is to generate an image of what you want to display, using AJAX if you want, then display it. But again, if users are zoom sets on 120% (like my grand parents), your image will be stretched.

Why do you want to specify a size using centimeters/inches ?

Comment: Images are also sized in pixels. So just producing an image wouldn't help because you still wouldn't know how many pixels to make it.

Comment: Using GD/Imagemagick on PHP, you can generate images using cm/inches size. The images will have the good size, however, they might not be displayed using their real size inside the browser.

Comment: They won't be displayed at their real size. Specifying physical units just adds meta data to the image saying how it should be scaled. It depends on the same DPI issues as I mentioned previously plus it requires that the software tries to render it at the physical size instead of the pixel size. Effectively, those sizes are for print (hard copy) use only.

Comment: Agreed, I used it on a project where I need to generate barcodes.